# Can you lose your pilot's certificate if you are convicted of a non-violent misdemeanor that doesn't involve drugs or alcohol?

Tags: pilot-certification

Can you lose your certificate, or be denied additional ratings, if you are convicted of a non-violent misdemeanor that doesn't involve drugs or alcohol?

Comment: Depends. What misdemeanor?

Answer (score 7):

There is no specific provision for the FAA to revoke your certificate or deny you any further ones even for a non-violent *felony*, much less a misdemeanor, as long as it doesn't involve drugs or alcohol.

However, 61.153(c) requires a candidate for an ATP certificate to be of "good moral character." It doesn't define this. Certainly not all misdemeanors are disqualifying, but certain combinations of misdemeanors are.